# Can't get appropriate values from query?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I want to list companyIds and with the mostly occur commentable type (0,1,2).

This is subquery

```
select a.companyId, a.commentable, count(1) _count
from article a
group by a.companyId, a.commentable

| companyId | commentable | _count |
|-----------|-------------|--------|
|         1 |           0 |      1 |
|         1 |           1 |      1 |
|         2 |           0 |   7759 |
|         2 |           1 |   7586 |
|         2 |           2 |   7856 |
|         3 |           0 |   7828 |
|         3 |           1 |   7866 |
|         3 |           2 |   7706 |
|         4 |           0 |   7851 |
|         4 |           1 |   7901 |
|         4 |           2 |   7738 |
|         5 |           0 |   7775 |
|         5 |           1 |   7884 |
|         5 |           2 |   7602 |
|        25 |           0 |   7888 |
|        25 |           1 |   7939 |
|        25 |           2 |   7784 |
```

For example above
Most commentable type occur for companyId=4  is 7901 and commentable type for that is 1. In below query , i see 4-0-7901, but i expected 4-1-7901

```
 SELECT x.companyId, x.commentable, MAX(x._count) _count
FROM 
(   SELECT a.companyId, a.commentable, COUNT(1) _count
    FROM article a
    GROUP BY a.companyId, a.commentable
) AS X
GROUP BY x.companyId;


companyId   commentable _count
1   0   1
2   0   7856
3   0   7866
4   0   7901
5   0   7884
25  0   7939

Expected result
companyId   commentable _count
    1   0   1
    2   2   7856
    3   1   7866
    4   1   7901
    5   1   7884
    25  1   7939
```

I dont understand 'why is all commentable column is '0' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `having` clause:

```
SELECT a.companyId, a.commentable, COUNT(*) as _count
FROM article a
GROUP BY a.companyId, a.commentable
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM article a2
                   WHERE a2.companyId = a.companyId
                   GROUP BY a2.commentable
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  );
```

In the event of ties, you will get multiple rows.  If you want only one row per company, you can instead use `commentable` for the comparison in the `HAVING`:

```
SELECT a.companyId, a.commentable, COUNT(*) as _count
FROM article a
GROUP BY a.companyId, a.commentable
HAVING a.commentable = (SELECT a2.commentable
                        FROM article a2
                        WHERE a2.companyId = a.companyId
                        GROUP BY a2.commentable
                        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                        LIMIT 1
                       );
```

As others have mentioned, your problem is the mis-use of `GROUP BY`.  The unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` need to match the `GROUP BY` keys -- and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

You need a big ugly join here.  In the query below, you may view the `GROUP BY` query on the company and comment type the base unit of work.  This query appears as itself, aliased as `t1`.  In alias `t2`, we subquery and aggregate only by `commentable`, to find the max count for each such comment type.  This, we join back to `t1` to restrict only the company having the max count.

```
SELECT
    t1.companyId,
    t1.commentable,
    t1.cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT companyId, commentable, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM article
    GROUP BY companyId, commentable
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT companyId, MAX(cnt) max_cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT companyId, commentable, COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM article
        GROUP BY companyId, commentable
    ) t
    GROUP BY companyId
) t2
    ON t1.companyId = t2.companyId AND t1.cnt = t2.max_cnt;
```

By the way, things get somewhat nicer in MySQL 8+, where we can take advantage of analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT companyId, commentable, COUNT(*) cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY commentable ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM article
    GROUP BY companyId, commentable
)

SELECT companyId, commentable, cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: ı am trying to apply your answer, it gives me reslt based on 'cnt'     2 2 7856 ||
25 0 7888 ||
25 1 7939

Comment: the t2 subquery probably should be `gropy by companyId`. try it like this https://rextester.com/XWBXR37118

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for all your edits.  Before you added the expected output, I guess I misinterpreted what was wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Cause `commentable` is not one of `group by` columns. In this case, with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled, MySQL is free to choose any one value for this column.

From [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks gavincook, i didn't know, ı am newly learned this. When i changed sql_mode to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,  query result  give grouped result, which ı dont want.